# How to install InstallShield 2010 SP1 (full edition) with Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I am not able to see any project template for InstallShield 2010 in Visual Studio 2012.

How to integrate InstallShield 2010 with Visual Studio 2012 after installing it?

I also tried this approach http://flexerasoftware.force.com/articles/en_US/HOWTO/Manually-Enable-Integration-with-All-Versions-of-Visual-Studio-NET. But no result.

Updated 22-Jan-2015
Today I found that installshield 2010 supports visual studio 2010.
[image: installshield 2010 supports VS 2010]
[image: installshield 2010 supports VS 2010-2]

Comment: What did you actually install, and in what order?

Comment: Big chance that InstallShield 2010 doesn't integrate at all in Visual Studio 2012, as it had no way of knowing how to do that at the time of release. You may need to upgrade to a later service pack or a later major version. InstallShield 2012 Spring Edition supports Visual Studio up to 2013.

Comment: @oɔɯǝɹ I installed visual studio 2012 first then installed installshield 2010.

Comment: @jessehouwing your comment seems to be the answser. I tried various ways, but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InstallShield 2010 was released far before Visual Studio 2012 ever saw the light of day, as such there was no way to integrate it when it shipped. As far as I can tell no Service pack to InstallShield 2010 ever brought this functionality.

The InstallShield 2012 edition is the first edition that integrates into Visual Studio 2012.

The full compatibility matrix is listed on the FAQ you quoted:

> Only certain versions of Microsoft Visual Studio .NET are supported with specific versions of InstallShield products. For example:
>
> - Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 2012 is supported by InstallShield 2012 Spring and later.
> - Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 2010 is supported by InstallShield 2011 and later.
> - Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 2008 is supported by InstallShield 2009 and later.
> - Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 2005 is supported by InstallShield 11.5 and later.
> - Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 2003 is supported by InstallShield X and later.
> - Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 2002 is supported by InstallShield Developer.

Comment: Today I found something interesting. visual studio 2010 supports installsheild 2010

Comment: Works in != Is supported. Installshield 2010 may no longer be the supported, it may work, but to get support from the creator, you may need to upgrade to 2011, as indicated in their documentation. (or the docs are wrong, that's also possible).